# GRASS GIS 7.4 in Linux for command line usage - setting up environment (.bashrc file)

Tags: grass-gis, linux, command-line, environment-variable, grass-7.4

I need to use GGRAS GIS 7.4.0 on Linux server (Debian 8.10 Jessie) via command line (with flag --exec) and I'm still having troubles with it.

Description: I compile and install GRASS GIS 7.4.0 with no problem on that machine. When I type

`grass74`

in terminal, the text GUI launch. But when I type some command ie.

`grass74 v.import input=some_shapefile.shp output=some_file`

or

`grass74 /root/grass74/test_loc/PERMANENT v.import input=some_shapefile.shp output=some_file`

it gives an

```
root@maptest:~# grass74 /root/grass74/test_loc/PERMANENT v.import input=/root/test_shp/test_point.shp output=bod 
Cleaning up temporary files... 
Starting GRASS GIS... 
ERROR: </root> is not a valid GRASS Location because PERMANENT Mapset is missing 
Exiting...
```

So I tried to set up .bashrc file for setting up GRASS GIS environments like at this page [Working with GRASS without starting it explicitly](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly).

In bashrc file, I added this lines:

```
export GISBASE=$GISBASE:/usr/local/grass-7.4.0
export PATH="$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$GISBASE/lib"
export GRASS_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$GISBASE/etc/python:$PYTHONPATH"
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:$GISBASE/man

generate GISRCRC
MYGISDBASE=$HOME/grass74
MYLOC=test_loc
MYMAPSET=PERMANENT

# Set the global grassrc file to individual file name
MYGISRC="$HOME/.grassrc74"

echo "GISDBASE: $MYGISDBASE" > "$MYGISRC"
echo "LOCATION_NAME: $MYLOC" >> "$MYGISRC"
echo "MAPSET: $MYMAPSET" >> "$MYGISRC"
echo "GRASS_GUI: text" >> "$MYGISRC"
```

Then restart server and type "grass74" again, but got this error:

```
root@maptest:~# grass74
Cleaning up temporary files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/grass74", line 2003, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/grass74", line 1884, in main
    clean_temp()
  File "/usr/local/bin/grass74", line 1621, in clean_temp
    call([gpath("etc", "clean_temp")], stdout=nul)
  File "/usr/local/bin/grass74", line 245, in call
    return subprocess.call(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Bad setting up environmental variables (bashrc file)? Or something else?

**EDIT:** 
I tried to modify command according to mankoff answer. I have created location at:

```
/root/grass74/pokus1/PERMANENT
```

and the command is:

```
grass74 EPSG: /root/grass74/pokus1/PERMANENT --exec v.import input=/root/test_shp/test_point.shp output=test_point
```

but I still get:

```
Cleaning up temporary files...
Starting GRASS GIS...
Executing <v.import input=root/test_shp/test_point.shp output=test_point> ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/grass-7.4.0/scripts/v.import", line 291, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/grass-7.4.0/scripts/v.import", line 173, in main
    **vopts) == 0:
  File "/usr/local/grass-7.4.0/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 413, in run_command
    ps = start_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/grass-7.4.0/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 380, in start_command
    return Popen(args, **popts)
  File "/usr/local/grass-7.4.0/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 74, in __init__
    subprocess.Popen.__init__(self, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Execution of <v.import input=root/test_shp/test_point.shp output=test_point> finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
```

**EDIT - OGRinfo output**

```
root@maptest:~# ogrinfo /root/test_shp/test_point.shp
INFO: Open of `/root/test_shp/test_point.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: test_point (Point)
```

Comment: Not sure if the following will resolve your issue, but the error 'No Such file or directory' relates to this `input=root/test_shp/test_point.shp `, you should include the `'/'` before `root`, i.e. 'input=/root/test_shp/test_point.shp'

Comment: No, even with "/" before root doesn't help. Still error 'No Such file or directory'.

Comment: what is the output of `ogrinfo /root/test_shp/test_point.shp`?

Comment: seems valid - see edit above

Comment: it's not totally clear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you simply want to get started with GRASS via the command-line? Or is there a specific reason you need to launch GRASS and import data from outside a GRASS session? Also, running the above as root, shouldn't cause issues, but it would be probably wise not to. I've tested your `v.import` command from bash on Debian and it works fine (provided the location & mapset were created).

Answer (score 2):

You don't give the error message from your first example: `grass74 v.import input=some_shapefile.shp output=some_file`. Because you don't specify a LOCATION and MAPSET it will use the last used one. But the command is incorrect as seen from the manual (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/grass7.html). You need to specify `--exec` as write you should in your opening sentence.

The second error message implies that you didn't create the `/root/grass74/test_loc/PERMANENT` LOCATION yet. You could perhaps do this by modifying that command to: `grass74 -c EPSG:<SOMETHING> /root/grass74/test_loc --exec v.import input=some_shapefile.shp output=some_file`.

See the `Batch jobs with the exec interface` section of the manual at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/grass7.html and use the syntax there.

Try this:

```
grass74 -c shapefile ./G
v.import input=shapefile output=dat
```

If that works, then, if `G` doesn't yet exist:

```
grass74 -c shapefile ./G --exec v.import input=shapefile output=dat
```

And if it does:

```
grass74 ./G/PERMANENT --exec v.import...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it but still get an error. See Edit in question.

Comment: You're not using GRASS correctly. Get it working interactively at the command line, then worry about non-interaction. You can't start it with `-c EPSG: `. That is invalid, and why I put the `<something>` in my answer. Either pass it a file (raster or shapefile) or EPSG code. I suggest starting with simpler use case before you dive in at the level you're trying to work.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the answer to the original question, but for anyone who found this post while facing the same newbie problem I was having: Re-evaluate the path of the file you're trying to reach. In my case, I was trying to do this:

```
docker-compose run --rm grass-service grass --text /output/grassdata
```

... when I simply needed to do this instead:

```
docker-compose run --rm grass-service grass --text /output/grassdata/PERMANENT
```

... which was why I was getting this:

> ERROR:  is not a valid GRASS Location because PERMANENT
> Mapset is missing

The error is not completely clear about what the problem is. You need to actually specify the PERMANENT Mapset, even though the error somewhat implies that the program can find it on its own.

Anyhow, now you know. Have fun!